# Laravel package's composer require problem on composer.json laravel/ui[v2.2.0, ..., 2.x-dev]

Tags: php, laravel, voyager, composer-php

I am trying solve a problem when I am installing Voyager. When I try to run `composer require tcg/voyager` I am getting some problem in console and can`t perform a normal install. What exactly do I have to change on composer.json?

Problem 1

```
- laravel/ui[v2.2.0, ..., 2.x-dev] require illuminate/console ^7.0|^8.0 -> 
    found illuminate/console[dev-master, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, 8.x-dev (alias of dev-master)] 
    but it conflicts with another require.
- laravel/ui v2.1.0 requires illuminate/console ^7.0 -> found 
    illuminate/console[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/ui ^2.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v2.1.0, v2.2.0, 2.x-dev].
```

my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "convertapi/convertapi-php": "^1.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "openpayu/openpayu": "^2.2",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.14",
        "pragmarx/tracker": "^3.5",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.8",
        "spatie/pdf-to-image": "^2.0",
        "tcg/voyager": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0",
        "tanmuhittin/laravel-google-translate": "^1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/HelperFunctions.php"
        ],
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "repositories": {
        "hooks": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://larapack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share more details? According to the error message, your composer.json requires `laravel/ui` in v2.1, but I cannot find that requirement in your file